# What is the best way to manage your environment specific app settings in Azure?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

My current setup stores the environment specific application settings within a section the ARM parameter files. So, the structure of ARM parameters files looks something like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "deploymentSpecificValues": {
      "value": {
        "subscriptionId": "0ce7bbfc-9fa4-46b5-8f38-303db907fd89",
        "environmentName": "dev",
        "azureBlobUri": "https://mytestblob.blob.core.windows.net/"
      }
    },
    "regions": {
      "value": [
        {
          "location": "West US",
          "additionalRegionData": "abc"
        },
        {
          "location": "West US 2",
          "additionalRegionData": "pqr"
        }
      ]
    },
    "webAppInfo": {
      "value": {
        "appName": "mytestapp",
        "appSettings": {
          "SqlServerConnectionString": "mySqlServerConnectionString",
          "Service1Url": "https://www.service1url.com",
          "Service2Url": "https://www.service2url.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "value": "Dynamic"
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the **appSettings** located under the **webAppInfo** node of the above code. Each environment has it's own parameters file like the above. I believe that the number of appsettings can keep growing with time and it might clutter the parameters files.

Questions:

1. Is this the best practice to manage appsetting?
2. If the answer to the above question is a no, then what's the best practice to handle the appsettings in such scenarios?

Comment: This approach is not bad at all. Another way of doing this is using IaC tools like Terraform or Ansible which give you more structure to the infrastructure and configuration management. For example, in Terraform you can use workspaces for different env and have only one parameter file to store different values per parameter for different env and use lookup in your terraform files to get the value of that parameter for that env. You get additional features with such tools as well. From experience, Terraform and ARM work great together.

Answer (score 1):

A couple thoughts:

- What you're doing is fine, but you're right in that 1) it could get unwieldy in param files and 2) generally these param files are in source control, so make sure what you have in there, should be in source.
- Check to see if there are values that you can get from the deployment at deployment time, e.g. subscriptionId can be returned from the subscription() function (assuming you want the id of the subscription you are deploying to).

There are two resources in Azure that you can use to store "config" - you can use them slightly differently.

1. KeyVault can store arbitrary strings (e.g. blobs of json) securely and they can be dynamically referenced (via parameters) at deployment time.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/key-vault-parameter

2. App-Config is a resource to store config values for just such an occasion - you can pull values out of the config store using the listKeyValue() template function

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-resource-manager
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-app-configuration

That help?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply @bmoore-msft! I'm aware of AppConfiguration might be useful here, but I want to limit the end user's access to the portal and control everything from the codebase. App configuration also presents a point of failure for my app in case the service isn't available. Thoughts?

Comment: appSettings are considered secrets so only users with contributor access to the resource can change it... if the users need to be contributors, then you can lock the resource to prevent changes.  AppConfigStore would only be used at deployment time, so if deployment succeeds, then your window for risk has passed.  That help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think this is a good practice to manage appsettings in ARM template like this.

But if you just want to add/update a setting, it is recommended to use azure portal or Azure CLI.

Reference:

[az webapp config appsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest)

Comment: just need to be careful with this approach as your templates and config become out of sync...